# How to formulate logical or constraint in cplex?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, cplex

How to write the following constraint in cplex?

1. the cost for full truck load is $700
2. and the cost of fractional truck load is \$800 *fraction up to $700

Comment: If you were asking for an OPL solution, then accept @Alex Fleischer's answer [pretty please]. -- Otherwise, also: please, specify the modeling/programming language you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//the cost for full truck load is $700
    // the cost of fractional truck load is $800 *fraction up to 700

float truckCost=700;
float truckPartialCost=800;

range r=1..3;

float values[r]=[5,6.5,6.9];
dvar float nbTruck[r];
dvar float cost[r];

// computation
dvar int intNbTruck[r];
dvar float floatNbTruck[r] in 0..0.99;

subject to
{
  forall(i in r) 
  {
    nbTruck[i]==values[i];
    nbTruck[i]==intNbTruck[i]+floatNbTruck[i];
    cost[i]==intNbTruck[i]*truckCost+minl(truckCost,floatNbTruck[i]*truckPartialCost);
  }
}

execute
{
  writeln(cost);
}
```

gives

```
[3500 4600 4900]
```

Nb: Some more info [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer/)